# Structure a table with many uneven rows and columns - HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to construct a table like the one in the snapshot using a SINGLE TABLE so that the content aligns properly when I want to print the webpage. How could I achieve this? This is my current code:

```
<table border="1" id="maintab">
    <tr>
    <td id="beg"> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Company logo"/> 
        <h3> Venkateshwara <br /> Enterprises </h3>
        <p> Shed No. D-30, Industrial Estate, </p>
        <p> B.H. Road, Tumkur - 572 103, Karnataka </p>
        <p> Mob: 94803 77407, 98440 91647 </p>
        <p> TIN: 29690400291 </p>
    </td>

    <td> 
        <table id="mid"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4> INVOICE </h4>
                    <p id="small"> Rule &#40;52A &amp; 173 of the Central Excise Rules 1984&#41; </p>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <h4 id="book"> BOOK COPY </h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" id="addr">
                    <p id="sma"> Name and Address of the Consignee </p>
                    <p> Amalgamated BEan Coffee Trdg. Co. Ltd. </p>
                    <p> No. 9, 2nd Floor, 7th Cross, N. S. Palya </p>
                    <p> Bannerghatta Main Road, </p>
                    <p id="last"> Bangalore - 560 076 </p>
                    <p> <b> PARTY'S VAT No: </b> 2688367839 <b> CST No: </b> 87236 </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" id="addr">
                    <p> Your Order No: PO/14/1060 </p>
                    <p> Order date: 04-02-2015 </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td>
        <table id="end">
            <tr>
                <td> Date: 9-2-15 </td>
                <td> Sl. No. 057 </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td> Date &amp; Time of Issue of Invoice </td>
                <td> 9-2-15 5.20 PM </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td> Date &amp; Time of Removal of Goods </td>
                <td> 9-2-15 5.30 PM </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td> Tariff Heading No. </td>
                <td> ------------------ </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td> Exemption Notification </td>
                <td> ------------------ </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> Sl. No. debit entry for duty in P.L.A./RG23 P.II </td>
                <td> ------------------ </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If it cannot be done using a single table, I would at least like to know how to maintain td width and height so that it is the same when i print the webpage. 
Thanks in advance! :)[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Your data doesn't appear to be tabulated, sans the third and fourth column to the right. You are better off using `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want..?? I've used **colspan** and **rowspan**. It looks like this.

[image: Output Table structure]

Try this code...

```
<style>
    .tablestyle {
        border: 2px solid;
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .tablestyle td {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    .tablestyle td h4 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .colcenter {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table cellpadding="10" id="maintab" class="tablestyle">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6" class="colcenter">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Company logo"/> 
            <h3> Venkateshwara <br /> Enterprises </h3>
            <p> Shed No. D-30, Industrial Estate, </p>
            <p> B.H. Road, Tumkur - 572 103, Karnataka </p>
            <p> Mob: 94803 77407, 98440 91647 </p>
            <p> TIN: 29690400291 </p>
        </td>
        <td class="colcenter">
            <h4> INVOICE </h4>
            <p id="small"> Rule &#40;52A &amp; 173 of the Central Excise Rules 1984&#41; </p>
        </td>
        <td class="colcenter">
            <h4 id="book"> BOOK COPY </h4>
        </td>
        <td> Date: 9-2-15 </td>
        <td> Sl. No. 057 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">
            <p id="sma"> Name and Address of the Consignee </p>
            <p> Amalgamated BEan Coffee Trdg. Co. Ltd. </p>
            <p> No. 9, 2nd Floor, 7th Cross, N. S. Palya </p>
            <p> Bannerghatta Main Road, </p>
            <p id="last"> Bangalore - 560 076 </p>
            <p> <b> PARTY'S VAT No: </b> 2688367839 <b> CST No: </b> 87236 </p>
        </td>
        <td> Date &amp; Time of Issue of Invoice </td>
        <td> 9-2-15 5.20 PM </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> Date &amp; Time of Removal of Goods </td>
        <td> 9-2-15 5.30 PM </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Tariff Heading No. </td>
        <td> ------------------ </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> Exemption Notification </td>
        <td> ------------------ </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p> Your Order No: PO/14/1060 </p>
            <p> Order date: 04-02-2015 </p>
        </td>
        <td> Sl. No. debit entry for duty in P.L.A./RG23 P.II </td>
        <td> ------------------ </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables are notorious for sizing themselves however they feel. The best trick is to add a div container as the only child of each td or th. The div container will maintain width and height effectively, and there should be no problem with the layout breaking down.

I have to say that a single table won't reporoduce this layout unless your central top cells are one row height as seen in the right-hand table, and your bottom central cells similarly one row high as compared to your right hand cells. If that were the case, then your first column would be a rowspan 6, middle rowspan 4.

If you do want the precise layout, you'll need an outer table with 3 cells, where central and right cells each contain child tables.

You could also try and render the 3 areas as float left block items, i.e. a div and 2 tables. They'd actually reflow vertically on narrow screens.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize resizing:

1. Set the width of each table in inches.
2. Set the widths of each column in inches.
3. Use `table-layout: fixed`.

Example HTML:

```
<table id="maintab">
  <col style="width: 2in">
  <col style="width: 4in">
  <col style="width: 2in">
...
  <table id="mid"> 
    <col style="width: 2in">
    <col style="width: 2in">
    <col style="width: 2in">
```

Example CSS:

```
#maintab, #mid {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#maintab {
  width: 8in;
}

#mid {
  width: 6in;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeb2uzn3/)**